# iterating pandas.core.series.Series in tweepy

Tags: python, iteration, series, tweepy

Hi I am just messing around with tweepy API to see if I can create an autoresponder to my DMs.

I have all of my keys entered.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
dms = api.list_direct_messages()

def extract_dms_as_df(dms):
    headers = vars(dms[0]).keys()
    data_points = [[getattr(i, j) for j in headers] for i in dms]
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_points, columns=headers)
```

---

Everything from above is correct and doesn't throw out an error.

```
dm_df = extract_dms_as_df(dms)
dm_df.to_csv()
```

This is what the csv looks like.

I want to integrate through the column '_json'

How would I do that?

### This is what I have so far.

```
def test():
    wf = []
    for key, value in enumerate(dms_df_json):
        wf.append(key)
    return wf
```

---

it is printing out just the actual number of rows.
Output:
[0, 1, 2]

Comment: Also I don't know if it helps but .list_direct_message() return a list of DirectMessage Objects. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: I am going over list comprehensions